# Question about flat base-change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, dominant-morphisms

Let $\varphi \colon X\to S_2$ be a proper dominant morphism between varieties. (This varieties has the same dimension in my example if it helps) I have another morphism $\psi\colon S_1\to S_2$ which is flat. $S_1$ is not necessary irreducible, it may has several components, but all of these component have the same dimension. Let $\varphi_\psi \colon X\times_{S_2}S_1\to S_1$ be the base change of $\varphi$.

> Is it true that for any irreducible component of $X\times_{S_2}S_1$, its image under the map $\varphi_\psi$ is dense in some irreducible component of $S_1$?

It is not difficult to show that $\varphi_\psi$ is dominant. But why $S\times_{S_2}S_1\to S_1$ cannot have some components which are "contracted" under the map $\varphi_\psi$?

Comment: I think you mean $X$ not $S$ in your question.

Comment: I don't understand your remark

Comment: You have not defined $S$.

Comment: Yes, of course. I've changed it.

Comment: The image of an irreducible component of $X\times_{S_2} S_1$ is irreducible in $S_1$ and so cannot be dense in $S_1$ if $S_1$ is not irreducible.

Comment: I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: Let $Y:=X\times_{S_2}S_1$ and let $C$ be an irreducible component of $S_1.$ If $D$ is an irreducible component of $Y$, then $\phi_\psi(D)=C$ iff $\phi_\psi(D)\supseteq C$. Now if this fails for all such $D$, then $C$ contains a non empty open subset (for the topology of $C$), which is outside $\phi_\psi(Y)$. But then $\phi_\psi$ is not dominant ($=$ surjective in this case by properness).

Comment: Yes, the fact that one such $D$ exists is clear. But the question is: does this hold for all $D$?

Comment: Sorry I realised that this does not exactly answer your question. I will think some more.

Comment: What assumptions do you place on $S_1$ - is it also a variety?

Comment: Yes, but not irreducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my own answer.

Let $Y=X\times_{S_2}S_1$ and $D$ be some irreducible component of $Y$. The image $\psi_\varphi(D)$ is dense in $X$ as $\psi_\varphi$ is flat and flat morphism is open. As $\varphi$ is dominant $\varphi(\psi_\varphi(D))$ is dense in $S_2$. This means that if we restrict  everything to some open subset of $U\subset S_2$  then $D$ is restricted to non-empty open subset $Z_U$ of $Z$.

Now general flatness says that over some open $U\subset S_2$ the morphism $\varphi$ is flat, so we can assume $\varphi$ to be flat. But in this case $\varphi_\psi$ is flat and hence open. The statement follows.

Comment: Be careful: a flat morphism is open under some finiteness conditions. Everything is fine for morphisms of varieties, but, for example, the inclusion of a generic point is a flat and non-open morphism.

Comment: In my case everything is of finite type over a field. Does it work in this case?

Comment: I think so. If $S_1$ is a variety, I don't see an issue.